# Synchronization primitive in latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, new-latin, genitive

I want to translate in to latin some of the names for the synchronization primitives I am programming.
[https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/os/sync.html](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/os/sync.html)

Semaphore was quite easy, since it means a apparatus for signaling. "organum signi" should work right?

Synchronization primative however is proving harder. Primative in this case is the more modern noun form found in STEM. It refers to the simplest version or most reduced form of something. Geometric primitives in computer graphics are the shapes which can be drawn and which are used to build all other shapes.

The best word I could find for primitive was "elementum". Synchronize comes from a greek word originally. And I did find a neo latin word for it,

synchronizo, synchronizare, synchronizavi, synchronizatus - verb 1st conjugation.

I'm still quite new to latin so help with how to construct this compound word is needed. How do I use a verb as a geneitve in order to say a element of synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

So Pacifica over on the latin discussion forum answered my question. You can construct an adjective based on the verb, with the suffix -orius, -oria, -orium and the perfect passive participle.

synchronizatus - perfect passive participle
synchronizatorius
synchronizatoria
synchronizatorium - adjective, the latin equivilant of synchronizing

"a synchronizing primitive" could therefore be translated as "elementum synchronizatorium"